Importing the file "...\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.targets" into the file "...targets\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Tool results in a circular dependency
There is virtually nothing about this error that I can find. I get this error when I try to open the properties on my project file. It shows this exception in the window instead of the properties. The first part of the exception text is as follows;

Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Query.QueryExecutionException: Importing the file "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.400-preview.0.24324.5\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.targets" into the file "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.113\targets\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Tooling.targets" results in a circular dependency.  C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.113\targets\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Tooling.targets ---> Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: Importing the file "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.400-preview.0.24324.5\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.targets" into the file "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.113\targets\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Tooling.targets" results in a circular dependency.  C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.113\targets\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Tooling.targets
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectLockService.d__72.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

I have no idea where to go from here. I have tried several things on my own in an attempt to fix this, but nothing has worked. Please help!
I am using VS2022 - Version 17.11.0 Preview 7.0
and am using the very latest .Net SDK.
This is a .Net Maui app for mobile if that matters
